# Export default an array of RouteConfig

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Is there a way to 'merge' the declaration of 'algo' and the export default?

For example. I have this piece of code:

```
import { HelloWorld } from './components';
import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router';

let algo: RouteConfig[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: HelloWorld
    }
]

export default algo;
```

Is there a way to do something similar to this?

```
import { HelloWorld } from './components';
import { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router';

export default RouteConfig[] = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: HelloWorld
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do something similar to this?

No. Sadly you need the declaration and `export default` statements separate unless you were exporting a function OR class.

Personally I don't use `export default` much : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html